# How does Git know which Index blob to add to a tree?

Tags: git

EDIT: If you downvote my question have a decency to say why.

In [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html) Ch9 the author says:

> Git normally creates a tree by taking the state of your staging area or index and writing a tree object from it.

My question is how does git know **which** of two consequitive index entries to create the Tree object from?

For example (the random numbers are meant to be 40-char SHA1's - I just made em up):

```
$ echo 'First change' > one.txt
$ git add one.txt 
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/1f/755a7fffe4   //first index entry

$ echo 'Second change' > one.txt
$ git add one.txt
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/2d/234asdf2   //second index entry

$ git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
$ git cat-file master^{tree}
100644 blob 2d234asdf2 one.txt  //How did it know not to take 1f755??
```

Does it just look at the blob timestamps?
Also - what happens to the first blob created - no one is referencing it. Does it just get destroyed or forgotten?

Comment: There's something very wrong with your git. First, you add `one.txt` and your object database gains on blob, then you add the (presumably already existing) `two.txt` and you only have one blob in your object database, it's lost the entry corresponding to `one.txt`. Also, your blob entries don't have the correct ids. What version of git are you using?

Comment: "git add two.txt" Did you mean "one.txt"?

Comment: @Thilo: Yah i mean one.txt Changed it. Sorry @Charles - typo. Ignore IDs I made them up :-)

Comment: @drozzy: Why did you make them up? Run _real_ commands and post the real results. Then we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: Why did I make HASHes? Why does it matter?

Comment: I don't understand your first question but it matters when you include in your question something that appears to be a log of commands run that it actually is a log of commands run. Otherwise the question is misleading and impossible to answer meaningfully. It's not hard to run the commands that you've shown and record their actual result (it took me no more that 30 seconds) and doing this would cause a lot less confusion.

Comment: Sorry, but anything that has a few numbers+digits in it is mean to be a 40 char SHA1. I am too lazy ;-)

Comment: @drozzy: Please try to be less lazy. I don't mind spending some time helping people but today it turns out that I wasted my time trying to work out how you were getting git to drop an object from its database with forcing a gc/prune. I then wasted more time trying to work out if you had a weird installation bug because your abbreviated SHA1's were not correct for the contents you were showing.

Comment: Man, I really like it when my question gets down voted without a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ```
   $ echo 'First change' > one.txt
   $ git add one.txt 
   $ find .git/objects -type f
   .git/objects/1f/755a7fffe4...   # first index entry (repository database)
   $ git ls-files --cached --stage --exclude-standard one.txt
   100644 1f755a7fffe4... 0       one.txt   # in 'the index'
   ```
2. ```
   $ echo 'Second change' > one.txt
   $ git add one.txt
   $ find .git/objects -type f
   .git/objects/2d/234asdf2...     # second index entry (repository database)
   $ git ls-files --cached --stage --exclude-standard one.txt
   100644 2d234asdf2... 0       one.txt     # in 'the index'
   ```
3. ```
   $ git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
   $ git cat-file -p master^{tree}
   100644 blob 2d234asdf2... one.txt  # the one from 'the index'
   ```
4. "git gc" would prune (remove) loose dangling object `.git/objects/1f/755a7fffe4...` (only after some delay, for safety reasons).

Comment: So... it keeps only the LAST "added" blob to index?

Comment: @drozzy: Index references LAST "added" blob, git-commit pick up the state described by index.

Comment: Got any proof of that? :-) By last you mean - chronologically last? What if I turn my clock backwards...

Comment: @drozzy: Last as in "last in the sequence".  Each "git add file" *overwrites* (updates to the new value) blob reference in the index.

Answer (score 1):

git creates the commit-tree from the file `.git/index`, the index stores the current tree and all related information. what you see in `.git/objects/…` are the actual blob objects of your file `one.txt`, not index objects

Comment: Yes I know that. But how does it know to take the SECOND blob not the first? Is there some pointer to the latest blob in the Index?
I mean when you ADD the file there is no TREE object created.